# Cannot Animate Custom Directive with ngShow

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-animate

I'm trying to animate a custom modal directive using ng-show, following the example shown on the [Angular](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/ngShow) website (example is at the very bottom of the page). However, I haven't had any luck getting it to work.

I'm using Angular 1.3.x with Bootstrap 3.3.x. I'm not using Angular UI Bootstrap because a custom modal directive is more flexible for my needs.

Here's what I've got so far:

Modal.js:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .directive('myModal', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: 'ModalCtrl',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.showModal = false;

        if (attrs.title === undefined) {
          scope.title = 'Modal Title Placeholder';
        } else {
          scope.title = attrs.title;
        }

        scope.$watch('showModal', function(isHidden) {
          if (isHidden) {

          } else {

          }
        });
      }
    };
  }).controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.$open = function() {
        $scope.showModal = true;
      };

      $scope.$close = function() {
        $scope.showModal = false;
      };
    }
  ]);
```

modal.html:

```
<div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal modal-fade" ng-show="showModal">
    <div class="modal-backdrop" style="height: 100%"> </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="content" ng-transclude></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

modal.css:

```
.modal-fade {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
}

.modal-fade .ng-hide-add .ng-hide-add-active,
.modal-fade .ng-hide-remove .ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}

.modal-fade .ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

index.html:

```
<my-modal title="Example Modal">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
</my-modal>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$open()">Open Modal</button>
```

Everything else works fine, i.e. the Modal shows up and can be closed, but there's no animation.

**Here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ss4ZBRbY8noVrYGD1Osm?p=preview) link to the code**.

Comment: can you throw this in a plunkr or a jsfiddle and link it?

Comment: Sure! Just added the plunkr link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS' animation hooks are implemented in a separate module called `ngAnimate`.

Load the script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

And add the module:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate'])
```

Secondly, you need to adjoin the CSS classes to form the correct selectors.

Instead of:

```
.modal-fade .ng-hide {
```

Do:

```
.modal-fade.ng-hide {
```

The first one is a decendant selector, which will select elements that have the class `ng-hide` and are descendants to elements with the class `modal-fade`.

The second one will select elements that have both classes, which is what you need.

For this scenario all you need is:

```
.modal-fade {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
  display: block;
}
.modal-fade.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The `display: block` is only needed to override `display: none` from the `modal` class in Bootstrap.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/h0tNOn6Xj31OGmHqulr5?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I didn't know ngAnimate was in another library. Didn't see that get mentioned in the docs. Also, another questions: How does Angular know when to apply the transition? Does it scan the CSS of the class the element has, for 'transition' tags when animation is activated?

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, it scans the element styles to get the CSS transition/animation duration and delay.